# Spring @RequestBody with Custom HttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring

When a client request is received
I want to bind my custom class `RouteSaveRequest.class`.
For this I created a CustomHttpMessageConverter.

but it dosen't work
why don't work CustomHttpMessageConverter readInterval
thanks for reading

```
2023-08-23 09:08:17.475  WARN 25216 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.example.core.route.dto.RequestSaveRoute["path"])]
CustomHttpMessageConverter.support()
```

```json
{
    "title":"First Route",
    "path":[[127.01202],[36.3030],
    ...]
}
```

```java
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString;
@Data
public class RequestSaveRoute {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private LineString path;
}
```

```java
@Component
public class CustomHttpMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<LineString> {

    public PointListHttpMessageConverter() {
        super(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        System.out.println("CustomHttpMessageConverter.support()");
        return LineString.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected LineString readInternal(Class<? extends LineString> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("PointListHttpMessageConverter.readInternal");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        double[][] coordinates = mapper.readValue(inputMessage.getBody(), double[][].class);

        GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

        Coordinate[] madeCoordinates = Arrays.stream(coordinates).map(e -> new Coordinate(e[0], e[1])
        ).toArray(Coordinate[]::new);
        return gf.createLineString(madeCoordinates);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(LineString points, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException {
        // Implementation omitted for brevity.
    }
}
```

here is my WebConfigurer & Controller

```
    // in Web Config 
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
        converters.add(new PointListHttpMessageConverter());
    }
    // in Controller
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveRoute(
            @RequestBody RequestSaveRoute request
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("success");
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need a custom converter for that? You should write a serializer for Jackson instead and just use the normal mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customise parsing just a JSON array (i.e. a part of request body) using `HttpToJsonMessageConverter`. So you have three ways:

1. Write a Json deserializer as M. Deinum wrote in the comment
2. Customize parsing for the entire `RequestSaveRoute` class. To do that you need to change the `CustomHttpMessageConverter` class.
3. Don't do what you wanna do. Cause you can go the other way, the easier way. More on this method below.

A way to separate transport and application logic. To do this, you need to create a DTO object, get it easily via HTTP in your controller and map it into another object related to the application logic. This way you will make your application simple and understandable. So you don't need any special converter.

```
@Data
// application logic class
public class SaveRoute { 
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private LineString path;
}

@Data
// DTO
public class RequestSaveRoute {
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Double[][] path;
}
```

So you can receive the DTO without any effort and map it to the application logic class in the easiest way. For example, using [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/)